# React Native: Implement custom client over websocket

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native for my application and as per my understanding below is the react native architecture

`native: Some thin UI layer on native mobile device
js: The actual js runtime
bridge: Handles the communication between native and js side. This communication can be over websockets`

In the above approach the js side defines how the UI should look like and react creates a virtual DOM and than pass that to native side and native side creates the UI from the virtual DOM. What I would like to achieve is define a custom client to js runtime.

Suppose I have a client which connects to react native server over websockets the server push the desired virtual DOM to the client the client do something with the DOM. The client also pass the client and other events back to server which server recognize and invoke the corresponding handlers in react component classes.

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDviGU-57lU) react under the hood video and I certainly know that it is possible to do so, but I am not able to figure out where to start and not finding any relevant documentation.

[This](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) guide from the react native tutorial is similar to what I am looking for but instead of [running the app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#run-your-app) on native device like android or ios I want this app to be independent. This app can be a simple console app and can simply logs the messages on the console which are received from the server via websocket communication.

To be more specific I am looking for something like this

```
For instance, if a React Native app is defined like this:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
<TextInput
    keyboardType="default"
    returnKeyType="done"
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}
    placeholder="Enter text here..."
/>

    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.key);
},

The server might send a JSON message to the websocket client that looks like this.  This is just a suggested format - the actual format just has to encapsulate a good view and be readable for review.  The true format will come in a later challenge, so all we're doing now is validating.

{
    "app": {
        "name": "Hello World",
        "view": {
            "text": "Hello World!",
            "textInput": "Enter text here"
        }
    }
}

Client

The client will open a connection to a websocket on the server.  Once the connection is open, it will send a simple message, like this:

{
    "onConnect": {
        "name": "React client1"
    }
}

The server will respond with the view details described above.

Then, the client can send an event, like a key press.  The event could look something like this:

{
    "event": {
        "type": "keyDown",
        "key": "Enter"
    }
}  

At which point the handleKeyDown callback would be called on the server.  An update to the text should then be sent from the server back to the client to complete the full loop.  This update to the text can just be something like below, but it should be fully implemented in React Native and then translated down for the client.

{
    "update": {
        "text": "Updated text"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is right about the react-native. One thing I want to add that react-native is a way to write ios/android app in Javascript and in React Framework style. So If you want to make an console app you can use React with Electron[If you want a desktop app] or there are react implementation for console app as well.

Comment: It's not just about console app, I want to leverage the power of react core concept i.e, UI = f(data) and I want to define my own custom UI layer.
I focus on react native because I want to stream the UI view from server down to some remote client via websockets. Is it possible to achieve this with react ? Can you refer some documentation ?

Comment: I see, I found this guide relevant to your usecase. http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/06/16/reactjs-and-socket-dot-io-chat-application/

Comment: You misunderstood this is not what I am asking, that is a simple chat application that renders in a browser. I want to implement my own UI layer.